# CodeContract warning

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I have a small utility class :

```
public static class SerializationUtilities
{
    public static string ToXml<T>(T @object)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(@object != null);
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(typeof(T).IsSerializable);
        Contract.Ensures(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()));

        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var result = new StringBuilder();

        using (var sw = new StringWriter(result))
        {
            xs.Serialize(sw, @object);
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }

    public static T FromXml<T>(string xml)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml));
        Contract.Ensures(!object.Equals(Contract.Result<T>(), default(T)));

        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var sr = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            return (T)xs.Deserialize(sr);
        }
    }
}
```

The two methods are working as expected.

However, the code contract static checker is throwing two warnings :

> Warning   30  CodeContracts: ensures unproven:
>   !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result())
>
> Warning   28  CodeContracts: ensures unproven:
>   !object.Equals(Contract.Result(), default(T))

Why are these warning emitted ? What is the correct (best?) way to contractualize my methods ?

Comment: Your Ensures can't be so strict. Most of framework methods aren't decorated with contracts. You can't be sure that StringBuilder.ToString() won't return an empty string because there is not information about what XmlSerializer.Serialize will do. Same for deserializing: no informations to assert that XmlSerializer.Deserialize won't return a default(T) object.

Comment: +1 for Adriano. You could at most do the `Ensure` that the result string is not null, then you can return an empty string. Or you could check if the `StringBuilder()` returned empty and then handle it appropriately. Same for the second method.

Comment: I just realize that if I have a value type serialized, it can have a default value. For example, if I serialize "0", my contract will fail, even if 0 can be the correct value.

Comment: @Adriano: answer to the question instead of commenting. You are actually answering it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Contract.Ensures()` can't be so strict.

Most of framework methods aren't decorated with contracts. You can't be sure that `StringBuilder.ToString()` won't return an empty string because there is not information about what `XmlSerializer.Serialize()` will do. Same for deserializing: no informations to assert that `XmlSerializer.Deserialize()` won't return a `default(T)` object.

As pointed out by @TrustMe-ImADoctor in the comment you may have to add additional checks in your code for that assertion, static analysis will then see that the case is handled and impossible. I guess you do not need to pollute your code with more checks, for this interop cases you may just use `Contract.Assume()`.

Comment: In fact, I think my approach is wrong. If the data is not correct, the serializer will fail to deserialize and throw an exception. That's ok and enough I think. So I'll simply wipe out my Ensures and keep my requires.